# Unsetting several indexes starting with a predetermined prefix

Tags: php, arrays, array-unset

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [game.info.campaign.end_date] => 2016-07-31, [game.info.campaign.start_date] => 2016-07-11, [game.info.campaign.peak_date] => 2016-07-21, [game.info.campaign.promo] => 'pokemon_go' );
```

I would like to unset all of them in a few line without repeating code. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

```
if (array_key_exists('game.info.campaign.end_date', $result)) {
    unset($result['game.info.campaign.end_date']);
}
```

I am doing the above right now, but there's too much repetition and some arrays have thousands of entries that start with the same prefix.

Comment: Just to be sure, the prefix is "game.info.campaign"?

Comment: Is that `Array()` initializer syntax valid with all the square brackets? Or is that pseudocode-ish?

Comment: sorry, it's pseudocode-ish.

Comment: @ajax If one of the below answers helped you, make sure to flag it as accepted to show the community that it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for a given prefix. Just `foreach` over the array and unset keys that start with `$prefix`.

```
$prefix = 'game.info.campaign';
$l = strlen($prefix);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, $l) == $prefix) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't mind making a new array rather than unsetting keys in your original array, using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` option (available in PHP 5.6+) will be much faster (3-5X in my tests).

```
$new = array_filter($array, function ($key) use ($prefix) {
    return strpos($key, $prefix) !== 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: Beat me to it by six seconds =)

Answer (score 1):

If the prefix is `game.info.campaign`, then you can loop over them and delete those with matching keys:

```
foreach($result as $key => $val)
    if(strpos($key, "game.info.campaign") === 0)
        unset($result[$key]);
```

This checks if the `$key` begins with `"game.info.campaign"` using PHP [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and unsets them.

See a [live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be82111b4f6ba3f83bf1fe697178dd10a03c6254).